# How is it possible that this differential equation has no integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The **differential equation** is the following:

$ydx+(\frac{y^2}{4}-2x)dy=0$

It can be written as:

$\frac{y}{2x-\frac{y^2}{4}}=\frac{dy}{dx}$

However, this is not the linear shape. So we rewrite the equation as:

$\frac{2x-\frac{y^2}{4}}{y}=\frac{dx}{dy}\to\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{2x}{y}=-\frac{y}{4}$

The **integrating factor** is:

$e^{\int{\frac{-2dy}{y}}}=\frac{k}{y^2}$ and k can't be zero (1).

If you **apply the integrating factor** to the original equation you get:

$\frac{k}{y}dx+(\frac{k}{4}-\frac{-2xk}{y^2})dy=0$

According to the **definition of an exact differential equation**, it must be true that the partial derivative in Y of $\frac{k}{y}$ is equal to the partial derivative in X of $(\frac{k}{4}-\frac{-2xk}{y^2})$. This leaves us with the equality:

$\frac{-k}{y^2}=\frac{-2k}{y^2}$

So the only possible solution is $k=0$, but this a **contradiction** (1).

How is it possible? Am I making a mistake? How can I get an integrating factor other than zero?

Comment: Is it exact? Don't you have to do something to make it exact? Should you get $$\mu = \dfrac{1}{y^3}$$

Comment: It is not exact, and that's the problem. If you use the integrating factor, the equation should be exact. But this way doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just apply the integrating factor to the original equation. You need to apply it to the equation that you computed it for.
$$
\frac1{y^2}\frac{xy}{xy}-\frac{2x}{y^3}=-\frac1{4y}
$$
is nicely integrable.

Comment: But both equations (the original and the one I use for compute the integrating factor) are the same, isn't it? The equation I use for compute the integrating factor is a simplification of the original (because I divided by "y"). It is like the following example: 2x+2y=0 is the same as x+y=0. So, if both are the same, why is not my solution correct ?

Comment: No, they are not the same. They are nearly equivalent, but they differ by a non-constant factor. And as the integrating factor is also a carefully tailored non-constant factor, it makes a difference if the first one is present or not.

Comment: What is the non-constant factor that they differ from?

Comment: The division by $y$. Note that the original equation does not have function fractions, while the equation that you compute the integrating factor for has a divisor $y$.

Comment: Now I see it clearly. To fix my integrating factor, we can subject it to the same change as the original equation. So, we divide my integrating factor by "y" and we get the correct result (I won't do the proof).

Answer (score 1):

$$ydx+(\frac{y^2}{4}-2x)dy=0$$
$$y\dfrac {dx}{dy}+(\frac{y^2}{4}-2x)=0$$
$$y\dfrac {dx}{dy}-2x=-\frac{y^2}{4}$$
The integrating factor is easy to find now.
$$y^2\dfrac {dx}{dy}-2yx=-\frac{y^3}{4}$$
$$\dfrac {y^2\dfrac {dx}{dy}-2yx}{y^4}=-\frac{1}{4y}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {x}{y^2}\right)'=-\frac{1}{4y}$$
As @Moo commented $\mu(y)=\dfrac {1}{y^3}$
. Now the DE is exact:
$$d\left (\dfrac {x}{y^2}\right)+\frac{dy}{4y}=0$$

Comment: I've never seen your method. I understand that you are looking for the derivative of the product on the left side of the equation. But why do you then divide by y^4?

I know the method described here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/linear.aspx. Specifically, I have used the formula called (10).

My method failed because, as Lutz rightly said in the comments to the other answer, I divided by a non-constant factor. But you do the same and I don't understand that.

Comment: well when you differentiate $(\frac f g)'=\dfrac {f'g-fg'}{g^2}$ this is  why I needed  $y^4$ at the denominator since $g=y^2$ @SergioDuránVega